# SQL Server Mgmt Studio shows "invalid column name" when listing columns?

Tags: sql-server, select, ssms

I'm used to scripting in Python or Matlab, and my first couple hours with SQL have been infuriating.  I would like to make a list of columns appear on the screen in any way, shape, or form; but when I use commands like

```
select * 
from "2Second Log.dbo.TagTable.Columns"
```

I keep getting the error:

> Invalid column name '[the first column in my table]'.

even though I never explicitly asked for [the first column in my table], it found it for me.  How can you correctly identify the first column name, and then still claim it's invalid!?  Babies will be strangled.

[image: My data structure, query, and the error message.]

This db was generated by Allen Bradley's FactoryTalk software. What I would really like to do is produce an actual list of "TagName" strings...but I get the same error when I try that.  If there were a way to actually double click the table and open it up and look at it (like in Matlab), that would be ideal.

Comment: try `select * from [2Second Log].dbo.TagTable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Echoing juergen's suggestion in the comment above. It looks like you're running the query on the `master` database, not the `2Second Log` database that actually has your table. (You can tell this by looking at the database in the dropdown in the top left of your screenshot). Two things you can do:

- Change the dropdown in the top left to `2Second Log`. This will target your query to a different database
- Put your database name in brackets as suggested by juergen i.e. `select * from [2Second Log].dbo.TagTable`

As an side, if you're looking for a good SQL tutorial, I highly recommend the [Mode SQL tutorial](https://sqlschool.modeanalytics.com/). It's a fantastic interactive platform to get your SQL feet wet.

Comment: Ah, now I understand - thanks!  And also, thanks for the tutorial link.  I'll check it out now. :)

Answer (score 1):

always use brackets when names/field have spaces or dashes.

```
select * from [2Second Log].dbo.TagTable
```